# Implement Autocomplete Search box _ASP.net MVC with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I need an autocomlete search box

[image]

I want to find any related question in database when user enters it's text.

Appreciate if some one help me in how to start with jQuery UI autocomplete. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery for recovering Data coming from controller (By Ajax), then you can use autocomplete method of Jquery as well...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#your_txt_box").autocomplete({
            source: function (request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'controller',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { field1: item.field1, field2: item.field2, field3: item.field3, field4: item.field4};
                        }))
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: thank you for your care .got it well but just a question.. is it possible for you to just tell me what this line is doing exactly? `response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { field1: item.field1, field2: item.field2, field3: item.field3, field4: item.field4};
                        }))`  and how I can do something each row alert by click if it'spossible. Appreciate

Comment: That function should be the object which you are getting from the controller, in your case a List<Question>. You must loop item for getting each item of the list, then you have to map each field you want to the autocomplete...
For doing something in every row, you have to define a Jquery function and call it from every onclick event in that row.
Autocomplete has an onclick event as well but only for itself... Anycase... That will be another question.

Comment: Excuse me again, what is `debugger;` for? it stops my code

Comment: Not, it was my fault. Sorry, you can delete it. I edited my answer as well... Cheers mate.